# How does a class get's initiated as a function argument?

Tags: php, class, instantiation

When a function has a class as an argument you can use this class without initiating it. Can someone explain how this class is initiated as a function argument? See code below for clarification.

```
    /**
     *
     * @param PseudoClass $class
     * @return void
     */
    public function pseudoFunction(PseudoClass $class)
    {
        // access PseudoClass instance from function argument
        $class->exampleFunction();

        // instead of manually creating a new instance of the PseudoClass
        new PseudoClass();

        $class->exampleFunction();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shows only the methods logic. In real life, you still need to instantiate the class you use before using it as the function's parameter.

Some frameworks use automatic injections, but they are still instantiated, however, under the hood.

Comment: That explains it, I use the laravel framework for my PHP projects. Laravel provides automatic injections thus allowing this code to work.

Comment: in case of laravel, all the classes are automatically bound via bind or singleton methods. Anytime you call them in your methods there is an instruction how to create an instance of that class. The instance is located in service container.
You can read this information here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container#automatic-injection

Answer (score 2):

It is not instantiated.  That is simply a parameter that has been typehinted to be a PseudoClass object.   A PseudoClass object must be created and passed to pseudoFunction for this code to work at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It is called DI (Dependency Injection). In Object Oriented programming we use this pattern but depends on the Design you follow.

> dependency injection is a technique whereby one object supplies the
>   dependencies of another object.

Use Case Example:

```
<?php

    class Skills {

        public function Web(){
            return 'Web Developer';    
        }

        public function Api(){
            return 'API Developer';
        }            

    }


   class Programmer {

      public function skill(Skills $skills){
         echo $skills->Api();
      }

   }

   // Instantiate Skills class to be used for DI.
   $skills = new Skills();
   $p = new Programmer();
   // DI occurs here.
   $p->skill($skills);
?>
```

Learn more about DI [here](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/dependency-injection-di-container-in-php-a7e5d309ccc6)